# Any way to get Input Pattern to work on Safari and IE8<

Tags: javascript, html, forms, internet-explorer-8, safari

I have a password form field that has 3 requirements: 8 characters in length; at least 1 number; at least 1 letter.

Here's what I did:

```
<input class="test" id="thepassword" title="Password Must Contain 8 characters with at least 1 number and 1 letter" type="password" name="thepassword" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])\w{8,}" placeholder="Create Password *" required="" />
```

This worked perfectly everywhere except Safari and IE8. Any way to get those browsers to play nice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On browsers that do not support the `pattern` attribute, the only way is to use JavaScript code that performs the same check. You could code it yourself (the difficult part is to decide what exactly should be done in error situations), or you could use some of the available [polyfill libraries for HTML5 forms](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#wiki-web-forms).